# Google TV with microphone

Tags: android, microphone, google-tv

Is there any solution to get sound from external microphone, connected to Google TV Box?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, no Google TV boxes come with microphones. In general, it wouldn't make sense for them given that they are usually around 10 feet away from the user (well I suppose the microphone can be included in the remote - but again - it hasn't been done yet).

With that being said though, a possible solution would be to have the user use his phone as the mic. So you would create some sort of app for typical Android phones that would connect to your app on the Google TV. You can then pipe the sound data to the Google TV (not fun... but possible).

Answer (score 1):

The webcam attachment for the Logitech Revue has a microphone built in:
http://www.logitech.com/en-us/smarttv/accessories/devices/7538